# Graphics Driver showing VESA: Broadway with AMD Catalyst Driver Installed

Tags: 12.04, ati, gnome

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I find out which driver a piece of hardware is using?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/50949/how-do-i-find-out-which-driver-a-piece-of-hardware-is-using)

I recently installed Ubuntu 12.04 as a fresh install. I followed the [Unofficial Wiki](http://wiki.cchtml.com/index.php/Ubuntu_Precise_Installation_Guide) to install the AMD catalyst driver version 12.4 from source.

In Gnome3 under 'All Settings' 'Details' 'Graphics' is shows Driver as VESA: BROADWAY. Is this correct?

fglrxinfo shows:

```
display: :0  screen: 0
OpenGL vendor string: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc.
OpenGL renderer string: ATI Mobility Radeon HD 5800 Series
OpenGL version string: 4.2.11631 Compatibility Profile Context
```

Xorg.conf show the fglrx Driver being used:

```
Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "aticonfig Layout"
    Screen      0  "aticonfig-Screen[0]-0" 0 0
EndSection

Section "Module"
    Load  "glx"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier   "aticonfig-Monitor[0]-0"
    Option      "VendorName" "ATI Proprietary Driver"
    Option      "ModelName" "Generic Autodetecting Monitor"
    Option      "DPMS" "true"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier   "0-LVDS"
    Option      "VendorName" "ATI Proprietary Driver"
    Option      "ModelName" "Generic Autodetecting Monitor"
    Option      "DPMS" "true"
    Option      "PreferredMode" "1680x1050"
    Option      "TargetRefresh" "60"
    Option      "Position" "0 0"
    Option      "Rotate" "normal"
    Option      "Disable" "false"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier   "0-DFP1"
    Option      "VendorName" "ATI Proprietary Driver"
    Option      "ModelName" "Generic Autodetecting Monitor"
    Option      "DPMS" "true"
    Option      "PreferredMode" "1680x1050"
    Option      "TargetRefresh" "60"
    Option      "Position" "1680 0"
    Option      "Rotate" "normal"
    Option      "Disable" "false"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier  "aticonfig-Device[0]-0"
    Driver      "fglrx"
    Option      "Monitor-LVDS" "0-LVDS"
    Option      "Monitor-DFP1" "0-DFP1"
    BusID       "PCI:1:0:0"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier  "amdcccle-Device[1]-1"
    Driver      "fglrx"
    Option      "Monitor-LVDS" "0-LVDS"
    BusID       "PCI:1:0:0"
    Screen      1
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "aticonfig-Screen[0]-0"
    Device     "aticonfig-Device[0]-0"
    DefaultDepth     24
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Virtual   3360 1920
        Depth     24
    EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "amdcccle-Screen[1]-1"
    Device     "amdcccle-Device[1]-1"
    DefaultDepth     24
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

Running gfl_glxgears shows a 3D rotating cube. How can I confirm Gnome is using the correct driver? Any assistance appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

im pretty sure that your installation worked correctly. I have the HD4850 one and after installing the closed source drivers got the same information.